# Concurrent methods execution in for loop

Tags: java, concurrency

There is the following method:

```
public void method(Collection<BigInteger> objectIds) {
    Collection<BigInteger> allObjectIds = new HashSet<BigInteger>(objectIds);
    for(BigInteger objId : allObjectIds) {
        SomeObject obj = getObjectById(objId); // obj.getColour(): red, green or blue
        if(isFirstGroup(obj)) { // the first group
            createInFirstGroup(obj);
        } else { // the second group
            createInSecondGroup(obj);
        }
    }    
}
```

It`s expected to get lots of `allObjectIds` as input. For better performance it`s needed to execute `createInFirstGroup`, `createInSecondGroup` concurrently, taking into account the following conditions:

1. all objects of `SomeObject` type can be divided into two groups - the first and the second. All incoming objects can be from the 1st group, the 2nd group or both.
2. `SomeObject` class has a field `colour`, which can be equal to 'red', 'green', 'blue'. Objects with different ids can have equal colour values. So, these objects with equal colour values can be inside each group (1st, 2nd or both). Their processing in `createInFirstGroup`, `createInSecondGroup` methods shouldn`t be concurrent in case of equal group and colour.

For example, the following combinations are wrong (x, y pair):

- thread x, y: (the 1st group, green; the 1st group, green)
- thread x, y: (the 2nd group, green; the 2nd group, green)

The following combinations are correct:

- thread x, y: (the 1st group, green; the 2nd group, green)
- thread x, y: (the 1st group, green;  the 1st group, red)

What are the correct ways (maybe there are some suitable patterns) to port the described `public void method(Collection<BigInteger> objectIds)` method (its for-loop part) into concurrent, providing optimal amount of threads and tasks distribution (taking into account described conditions)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super clear on your constraints, but one general approach would be a pipeline connected by queues.  You could use a blocking queue to apply back-pressure.  The following is "actor" inspired where each actor is single threaded receives off of a blocking queue and publishes to an output queue, with the exception of the source and the sink.  You could implement the whole pipeline in terms of this where coordination will occur between the source and the sink so the sink knows when to complete.

- Source -> collects & writes objectIds -> to a queue
- <- `getObjectById` thread reads from previous and writes -> to output queue
- <- Create in group thread, checks for first/second and creates -> writes to output
- <- Final sink reads from previous 2 outputs